# Merging/ Extending Typescript React-Native interfaces

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, types

So I've a little dilema here, I'm using react native together with Typescript.

Have @types/react-native installed which has an interface 'TextInputStatic' declared under node modules @types/react-native.

```
export interface TextInputStatic extends NativeMethodsMixin, TimerMixin, React.ComponentClass<TextInputProperties> {
    State: TextInputState;

    /**
     * Returns if the input is currently focused.
     */
    isFocused: () => boolean;

    /**
     * Removes all text from the input.
     */
    clear: () => void;
}
```

In my component I need to use custom props for TextInput but because of interfaces defined in node modules typescript compiler throws an error:

```
Type '{ prop1: { name: string; anonymous: boolean; }; prop2: "f"; }' has no properties in common with type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<Component<TextInputProperties, ComponentState, nev...'.
```

When used like this:

```
<TextInput prop1={{name: 'loginField', anonymous: false }} prop2='f'></TextInput>
```

I looked at merging/ extending interfaces but no luck so far. Anyone knows how can I extend or allow TextInput to have custom props?

What I've tried to do is created an index.d.ts file and then:

```
import * as Native from 'react-native';

interface InputType extends Native.TextInputStatic{
    prop1?: any;
}
```

But no luck

Thanks

Comment: Make own component which wraps `TextInput`?

Comment: I was hoping I'd be able to write an interface or type that extends TextInputStatic or something like that

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html Something along the lines of this

Comment: Are you importing `TextInput` in your file?

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to get the type from the component itself. Like this:

```
type TextInputStaticType = React.ComponentProps<typeof TextInputStatic>
```

Then you can extend the interface or type from there.

Answer (score 0):

TextInputProps useable from reac-native >0.72 package